# Why do the StringBuilder Append methods return a StringBuilder object?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

So if you take a look at any of the Append methods of a 'StringBuilder', the return type is `StringBuilder`. Not a string or a count of lines or anything you might think could be even intuitively useful. Ostensibly (I haven't checked this yet), it's the same `StringBuilder` object that you just called the method on.

I can't really see a reason for that. Is there one?

Comment: this allows chaining. `sb.append("Hello").append("World");`. vs. `sb.append("Hello"); sb.append("World");`.

Comment: Really? Is that it? That's kind of weird...

Comment: That is not weird, it is called the builder pattern

Comment: Part of the benefit of StringBuilder is to avoid creating an excessive number of strings. If append returned a string every time you appended a value, that works against the idea, imo.

Comment: No, I get that. Just wondering why StringBuilder would need to return itself on an append.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The builder pattern is when you have a mutable object used to create an immutable object.  (Technically a StringBuilder is following that pattern, but only because it's a mutable builder for an immutable string, append could return `void` and it'd still follow the builder pattern.)  It's not the pattern describing a method that returns the instance it's a member of.

Comment: Pretty sure the correct moniker here is a ["fluent interface"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

Comment: @Servy You're right, I was thinking of the mashup of fluent interface and builder: [fluent builder](https://medium.com/@martinstm/fluent-builder-pattern-c-4ac39fafcb0b)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen A real fluent interface is when the API uses immutable objects and the functions are all pure methods.  Having methods only used for their side effects that return the instance object is just a way to attempt to emulate that pattern.

Comment: Because the whole point of the StringBuilder class is to provide *efficient* objects to build strings.  Once you are done building your string *then* convert it back ToString.  It would be inefficient to be constantly converting back and forth between String objects and StringBuilder objects.

Comment: @Servy Keeping your methods side-effect free/purely functional is certainly _highly desirable_ in such an API, but I don't think the lack of functional purity makes `StringBuilder`'s public API surface  "not fluent" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple form of what is called a "fluent interface" or "fluent API". (see [This wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)) APIs following that pattern allow chaining of methods, which may look weird in the beginning, but may make the code natural to read. Another well-known API implementing this is `linq`, where you can write things like

```cs
myList.Where(x => x.Element1 > 1).OrderBy(x => x.Element2).Select(x => x.Element3);
```

Or, as a really sophisticated sample of a fluent API, a task description from [Nuke build](https://nuke.build/):

```cs
Target CompileForMatlab => _ => _
    .Executes(() =>
    {
        MSBuild(s => s
                    .SetSolutionFile(Solution)
                    .SetConfiguration(Configuration)
                    .AddTargets("Restore,Build,Publish")
                    .SetProjectFile(Solution.GetProject("ExtendedLogParser"))
                    .SetOutDir(ArtifactsDirectory / "ExtendedLogParser")
                    .SetProperty("Platform", Platform)
                    .AddProperty("SelfContained", true)
                    .AddProperty("RuntimeIdentifier", "win10-x64")
                    .AddProperty("PublishDir", "../ExtendedLogParser")
                    .DisableNodeReuse());
    });
```

Comment: LINQ is *actually* fluent, as it is a result of pure methods that each produce an output based on their input and have no side effects, and that can often be chained when the output of one method is only ever needed as the input for another (which is quite common when dealing with pure functions), and thus has no reason to be stored in an intermediate variable.  Methods only used for their side effects returning the instance in this way is emulating the form and not the function of the pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation. 13 years as a developer, I only just noticed this, and really found nothing on Google.

Comment: @Servy: True, it is a bit different, but it is quite common as well, when functions that could return void actually return "this", because, if it's unused it doesn't hurt. The Wikipedia article actually does mention both cases.

Comment: @PMF Constructing an API that appears to be something very different than what it actually is doing *does* have a cost.  Not necessarily in CPU cycles (although there is technically a small performance cost here too), but it does have a cost.  That this question exists is a great example of it.

Comment: If the cost is readability, yes, I'm with you on this one. Especially with things like the Nuke example above, I'm not really sure that's the best way of designing an API. When Linq first came up I first tried hard not to use it, because its syntax was really weird - and having a syntactically clean, structured language was one of the main reasons for switching from C++ to C# some years before they added that.